# How to use extra function to aggregate a table separately django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How to use extra function to aggregate a table separately django?

I tried the example below, but I did not succeed.

Thank you very much for your attention.

```
aulas = Aula.objects.extra(
            select={
        'reposicao': 'SELECT * FROM app_reposicao WHERE app_cfc_reposicao.id = app_aula.id_tipo'
        })
```

> subquery must return only one column LINE 1: SELECT (SELECT * FROM
>   app_reposicao WHERE app_reposi...

Comment: instead `*` you should use one column name. This is the error message info.

Comment: Can not select entire line?

Comment: yes can not do it.